# dynamoDB FilterExpression on own slice

Tags: database, go, amazon-dynamodb

I working on easy access to dynamoDB and I can't find out how to get object according to some props in own slice. What I need is a right expression.

I have this model:

```
type aaa struct {   
    Aa string         `json:"aaa"`
    Ac []bbb          `json:"aac"`
}

type bbb struct {   
    Ba string   `json:"bba"`
}
```

with this data

```
    a := &aaa{
    Aa: "Aa",
    Ac: []bbb{
        {
            Ba: "foo1",
        },
    },
}
```

for me is working expression like this

```
expression.Name("aac[0].bba").Equal(expression.Value("foo1"))
```

but i dont know index. 
So I was trying

```
expression.Name("aac.bba").Equal(expression.Value("foo1"))
```

but **this is not working**.
I also trying contain

```
expression.Name("aac.bba").Contains("foo1")
```

but this was working only on scalar types.
Any Idea how get the object if i don't know index? Thanks

Comment: did you try with an object in contains? something like {Ba : "foo1"}

Comment: no, in sdk-v2 is accepting `Contains` only string